# Vue http GET request with Query String Parameters and FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, http

im trying to figure out how to send GET request with FormData and Query String Parameters. Exactly like the picture below.

[image: It should look like this in chrome dev tools]

Now I can only send Query String Parameters with my code below. Here's my GET method:

```
const OPTIONS = {
  credentials: true
}

function isResponseValidString (response) {
  return typeof response.body === 'string'
}

function isResponseValidObject (response) {
  return typeof response.body === 'object'
}

get (endpoint, options = {}) {
    Object.assign(options, OPTIONS)

    return Vue.http.get(endpoint, options).then(
      response => {
        if (isResponseValidString(response) || isResponseValidObject(response)) {
          if (response.body.data && typeof response.body.data !== 'object') {
            return Promise.reject(response)
          }
          return Promise.resolve(response)
        }
        return Promise.reject(response)
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      })
  }
```

and here's how i use it:

```
const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('id', this.id)

apiClass.get(ENDPOINTS.block, { params: { id: this.id } }).then(response => {
        console.log('r', response)
      }, error => {
        console.log('e', error)
      }).finally(() => {})
```

What should i change to be able to send also formData?

Comment: I think it's not possible with that method. Here's what I found: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/471

Comment: If using the fetch API is an option for you, I'd look into that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch